# Django: What is the simplest way to shorten the application url?

Tags: django, django-urls, application-settings

I have a Django application that has a long name "encyclopedia".  I would like the url for the application that appears on the address bar to be something shorter like "http://127.0.0.1:8000/ency" instead of "http://127.0.0.1:8000/encyclopedia" .  What is the simplest way to accomplish this without compromising the functionality of the application?

I suspect its something very simple like modifying ROOT_URLCONF in settings.py.  There is a general lack of examples that illustrate how to in [the documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#urls).

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/django-url-shortening/

Comment: I don't know how to answer this question as asked. I think what you want is `urls.py` which the `ROOT_URLCONF` points to. You can match on arbitrary strings and include the urls from the application. see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a separate urls.py file for the Django application "encyclopedia", simply include it as follows in the main urls.py file of your project:

```py
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ency/', include('encyclopedia.urls')),
]
```